# Compression library for C / C++ able to deal with more than 32 bit elements in the array

Tags: c++, compression, zip

I have a problem in the fact that I need to compress around a 6 GB `std::vector()` (1.5 billion `float`s in it), and up to now I have used lz4, but it only handles `int` count of `char`s. Since I have 6 billion chars in my vector, that would need 33bit to represent, and the compression with LZ4 does not work as I need it to.

From what I saw at the zlib libraries, it takes int as well as input for the length of the to compressed data.

Do I need to segment my data, or is there a framework around able to deal with more than 32bit of `char`s, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'd segment for now as it's the easiest solution and you already have the code for it.  You won't lose much efficiency at those sizes and won't have to learn/import a new system...

Comment: I know it's not central to your question, but you might want to clarify whether you mean `float`s or `char`s - you seem to be using them interchangeably.

Comment: I have 1.5billion floats in the array, but the compression takes an array of char as input, thus the length is 6 billion char.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Michael - segmenting seems like a fairly simple solution compared with switching to a different library. I'd write a wrapper class which handles it, so that your calling code doesn't have to care whether the data is being segmented or not. Then, if you decide to upgrade the library later, your main code is unaffected.

Comment: Yes, chunk the input into smaller input blocks. This is the way to go. Note that's what libraries handling >4GB input are doing anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zlib, and pass the array in as several chunks. The DEFLATE algorithm used by zlib has a window size of about 32 KB, and it already buffers the compressed data, so passing the data in as multiple chunks will not affect the compression efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XZ](http://tukaani.org), it seems to handle really big sizes. The CLI executables themselves are thin wrappers over a library, so this should fit your bill.

OTOH, a stream of *binary* floats shouldn't compress that well...

Comment: How well a stream of binary floats compresses depends on the stream contents. Given a good compression algorithm, it compresses to the same size as the compressed textual respresentation. E.g. `std::vector<float>(1000000, 0.0f)` compresses well, whether represented as text or binary.

Comment: The compression shouldn't be too bad, since all floats are in the range of 10-30, so the exponent will be very similar most of the time. If I zip the raw files, it gives me around 60% compression, which is perfectly fine for me.